# combine terms and bool query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do a search in an elasticsearch index but only for a list of ids. I can select the ids with a terms query

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "_id": list_of_ids
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to search in the resulting list, which can be done with a query like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {}
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I combine those two queries?
One solution I found is to add the ids into the must query like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {}
            "should": [{
                "term": {
                    "_id": id1
                },
                "term": {
                    "_id": id2
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which works fine. However, if the list of ids is very large it can lead to errors.

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query:
```

I am wondering whether there is a more compact way to write such a query? I think the error above is caused by my query just being too long since I added thousands of term searches... there must be a way to just provide an array, like in the terms query?

Answer (score 0):

solved it

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {},
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "_id": list_of_ids
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sorry I am a bit of a newbie to elasticsearch...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [IDs query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html), which returns documents based on their IDs.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result.

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"buiscuit",
    "cost":"55",
    "discount":"20"
}
{
    "name":"multi grain bread",
    "cost":"55",
    "discount":"20"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "bread"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "ids": {
          "values": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "4"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65431114",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5754429,
        "_source": {
          "name": "multi grain bread",
          "cost": "55",
          "discount": "20"
        }
      }
    ]
```